# On the surface, JPA Criteria Queries are a huge step back from Hibernate Criteria Queries. Is this really the case?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

How could such a colossal step back be justified!?!  Am I missing something?  The readability of the entity manager version is just awful.

session().createCriteria(Entity.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id"), id).uniqueResult();

versus

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
try {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Transaction> cq = cb.createQuery(Transaction.class);
    Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();
    EntityType<Transaction> Transaction_ = m.entity(Transaction.class);
    Root<Transaction> transaction = cq.from(Transaction.class);

    // Error here. cannot find symbol. symbol: variable creationDate
    cq.where(cb.between(transaction.get(Transaction_.creationDate), startDate, endDate));

    // I also tried this:
    // cq.where(cb.between(Transaction_.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("creationDate"), startDate, endDate));

    List<Transaction> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    return result;
} finally {
    em.close();
}
```

Comment: You can use strings if you really want to (rather than metamodel) ... and the author(s) of Hibernate were behind JPA Criteria IIRC. That aside, both of them are several steps behind the likes of QueryDSL, and JDO Typesafe.

Comment: Thanks for the QueryDSL shout out.  I have just heard it elsewhere too and it looks like a great option!